# Check and modify Capitalized letters in string

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to make this code work.
I input some text via variable into code:

```
$genome  = "ss/ee/ff/Nn/oo";
$gepieces = explode("/", $genome);

$fenome  = "ss/Ee/ff/nn/oo";
$fepieces = explode("/", $fenome);
```

You will see that for the Genome there is a Nn and for the Fenome there is a Ee
Upon this happening I need it to give a 50/50 chance for a compared result to be EITHER Ee OR Nn - The code I have right now can only check them individually (so sometimes I ger Ee AND Nn, other times I will get ee and nn) and I feel there could be a much easier method of achieving this than what I'm trying:

```
//Number of Cubs
$cubs = rand(1,4);

//GENDER
for ($x = 0; $x < $cubs; $x++) {
    $gender = rand(1,2);
    if ($gender == 1) {
        $cubgender = "Male";
    } elseif ($gender == 2) {
        $cubgender = "Female";
    }

    //COAT COLOR
    $genome  = "ss/ee/ff/Nn/oo/Pa/Sr/So";
    $gepieces = explode("/", $genome);

    $fenome  = "ss/Ee/ff/nn/oo/Pa";
    $fepieces = explode("/", $fenome);

    if ($gepieces[0] === $fepieces[0]) {
        $ss = $gepieces[0];
    } else {
        $ss = rand(1,2);
        if ($ss == 1) {
            $ss = $gepieces[0];
        } else {
            $ss = $fepieces[0];
        }
    }

    if ($gepieces[1] === $fepieces[1]) {
        $ee = $gepieces[1];
    } else {
        $ee = rand(1,2);
        if ($ee == 1) {
            $ee = $gepieces[1];
        } else {
            $ee = $fepieces[1];
        }
    }

    if ($gepieces[2] === $fepieces[2]) {
        $ff = $gepieces[2];
    } else {
        $ff = rand(1,2);
        if ($ff == 1) {
            $ff = $gepieces[2];
        } else {
            $ff = $fepieces[2];
        }
    }

    if ($gepieces[3] === $fepieces[3]) {
        $nn = $gepieces[3];
    } else {
        $nn = rand(1,2);
        if ($nn == 1) {
            $nn = $gepieces[3];
        } else {
            $nn = $fepieces[3];
        }
    }

    if ($gepieces[4] === $fepieces[4]) {
        $oo = $gepieces[4];
    } else {
        $oo = rand(1,2);
        if ($oo == 1) {
            $oo = $gepieces[4];
        } else {
            $oo = $fepieces[4];
        }
    }
echo $cubgender." - ".$ss."/".$ee."/".$ff."/".$nn."/".$oo."<br/>";

}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easier why to do that, but there's defenitely a shorter way to code it (in a loop f.e.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a colossal idiot!
Figured out my own issue

```
//Number of Cubs
$cubs = rand(1,4);

//GENDER
for ($x = 0; $x < $cubs; $x++) {
    $gender = rand(1,2);
    if ($gender == 1) {
        $cubgender = "Male";
    } elseif ($gender == 2) {
        $cubgender = "Female";
    }

    //COAT COLOR
    $genome  = "ss/ee/ff/Nn/oo";
    $gepieces = explode("/", $genome);

    $fenome  = "ss/Ee/ff/nn/oo";
    $fepieces = explode("/", $fenome);

if ($genome === $fenome) {
    $cubgeno = $genome;
} else {
    $cubgeno = rand(1,2);
    if ($cubgeno == 1) {
        $cubgeno = $genome;
    } else {
        $cubgeno = $fenome;
    }
}

echo $cubgender." - ".$cubgeno."<br/>";
```

Comment: this looks wrong, since there are actually four possible cases
what about sseeffnnoo or ssEeffNnoo ?

Comment: `if ($genome === $fenome)` makes no sense here

Answer (score 0):

```
$genome  = "ss/ee/ff/Nn/oo/Pa/Sr/So";
$gepieces = explode("/", $genome);

$fenome  = "ss/Ee/ff/nn/oo/Pa";
$fepieces = explode("/", $fenome);

$sequence = "";
for ($i = 0;$i < count($fepieces); $i++) {
 rand(1,2) == 1 ? $sequence .= $gepieces[$i] : $sequence .= $fepieces[$i];
}
echo $sequence;
```